# How to get an array of features at Openlayers 6?

Tags: openlayers, geoserver, openlayers-6

I want to get an array of features which I could add to the map with WFS. I am hosting the features from my own computer (GeoServer). There is no problem at displaying the features on the map but I can not reach to features of the layer. I intend to get an array of features and populate a ComboBox with the features.

Here is my code:

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import {Map, View} from 'ol';
import {Tile as TileLayer, Vector as VectorLayer} from 'ol/layer';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector';
import GeoJSON from 'ol/format/GeoJSON';
import {Stroke, Style} from 'ol/style';
import WFS from 'ol/format/WFS';


const lyrOSM = new TileLayer({
  source: new OSM()
});

const vectorSource = new VectorSource();

const lyrNeighborhood = new VectorLayer({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: new Style({
    stroke: new Stroke({
      color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1.0)',
      width: 2
    })
  })
});

// generate a GetFeature request
const featureRequest = (layer) => {
  return new WFS().writeGetFeature({
    srsName: 'EPSG:3857',
    featureNS: 'bugra',
    featurePrefix: 'Bugra',
    featureTypes: [layer],
    outputFormat: 'application/json',
  });
};

// then post the request and add the received features to a layer
fetch('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Bugra/wfs', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(featureRequest("ABS_MAHALLE_M"))
}).then(function(response) {
  return response.json();
}).then(function(json) {
  const features = new GeoJSON().readFeatures(json);
  vectorSource.addFeatures(features);
  map.getView().fit(vectorSource.getExtent());
});

const view = new View({
  center: [0, 0],
  zoom: 1,
});

const map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [lyrOSM, lyrNeighborhood],
  view: view
});

const features = vectorSource.forEachFeature((feature) => {
  console.log(feature);
});

console.log(features);
```

The last part of the code is returning `undefined`

```
const features = vectorSource.forEachFeature((feature) => {
  console.log(feature);
});

console.log(features);
```

Also this is not working:

```
lyrNeighborhood.getSource().forEachFeature((feature) => {
  console.log(feature);
});
```

Comment: You will not have any features until the callback from the fetch completes.  Put your code to get them inside the callback after the `ectorSource.addFeatures()` or alternatively add a listener such as `vectorSource.on('addfeature', .... );` and put your code inside that.

Comment: But my fetch completes and i can see the features on the map? Is not there any way to be able to get the features after i see the layer on the map? 

const features = new GeoJSON().readFeatures(json);
it works when i use this "features" but i can not use it outside the fetch code.

Comment: Simplest to use the `features` in the callback function, when/where they are available.  Alternatively, you can save them in a variable that is available outside the scope of the callback, and use them after the callback runs, but you have to structure your code such that you are sure to be using them __after__ they are available.

Comment: Thank you. I think i am going to stick to the "features" in the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch is like any other asynchronous method, for example

```
let message = 'I have no features';
setTimeout(function(){message = 'I have some features';}, 5000);
console.log(message);
```

The console will show the value of message when you set the timeout, not when the timeout completes.